# Constructing batch file command line using arguments

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, bcp

I was tried exporting data from SQL Server table to `.csv` file and for that, I'm using the `BCP` utility in a batch file. My requirement is to pass `database name`, `filename` and `server name` as arguments.

```
bcp %1.dbo.temp_raw_MSPsalesrecordExtract out \\192.168.17.95\NonProdData1\CMA\ChennaiDA\Selva\%2.csv -c -t"|" -S "%3" -T
```

while running got an error

C:\Users\selva\Desktop\Bat>bcp.bat selva_test testfile ind-server01

> The input line is too long.
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Try shortening the file path. This will reduce the command length by a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SteveFest. 

The problem here is with the filename "**bcp.bat**" because it is a name of **system batch file**. So, when I executing the batch file "bcp.bat" it is automatically getting redirected to the system batch file.

I tried renaming my batch file and it is working fine now.